# TSA Pre - I can’t find my membership number

Tags: usa, tsa-precheck

Looking for my TSA Pre membership number.  I know that American Airlines has it.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I bet it's not in OP's AA profile. It was used on an AA reservation only.

Answer (score 2):

If you have NEXUS, SENTRI or Global Entry, the number [is on the back of your card and starts with 98](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/faq).

If you're a member of TSA Pre and forget your number, [you can look it up via this website](https://universalenroll.dhs.gov/workflows?workflow=service-status&servicecode=11115V).

Comment: Since the OP indicated that it is saved in their AA profile, it might be good to point out that most airlines call it the *Known Traveler number* or *Known Traveler ID*.

Answer (score 2):

Log into your account on aa.com, click on “Hello, *name*” and “your account”. There, click “information and password” and then scroll down to the “secure traveler” section. You’ll find your number in the “known traveler number” field.